# regression model with randomForest in raster package

Tags: raster, regression

I'm learning randomForest classification method in R and I performed land-use classification with randomForest and raster packages. But when I try uesd a regression model produced with randomForest to predict in "raster" with the same operation, there is only a NA value RasterLayer left.[image]

what is wrong, the way I deal with datas or it can't do this in "raster" package

Comment: You are not giving us a reproducible example and it is very unclear exactly what you are asking. Have you fit a regression instance of RF? If so, on what data? It is a bad idea to fit a regression to catagorical (e.g., landcover) data. Are the rasters you are defining in the predict function actually in the model? If you provided your code and not just a screen shot of the error message the community may be able to provide some relevant advice.

Comment: thank all your helpful advises. I have result it, there is something wrong with my independent variable, there is one variable is factor, when I change it to

Comment: @logan I notice that you have two accounts.  Please visit this [page](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on how to merge them.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to know from your description. But you can try things like the below to see what is going on:

```
# get values of a few cells
cells <- 100000:100010
x <- data.frame(w1[cells])
x

predict(s2.rf, x, type='response')
s2.predict[cells]
```